# Button is lower than the other elements

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am making a very simple site for my application, but I still want it to not look half hearted. Currently, I cannot get the button aligned to the other two elements properly.

current result:

[image: Picture Reference]

I want all elements in the picture to align properly on a single line.

Here is my code so far:

```css
#progress-bar {
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#loading-bar {
    background: greenyellow;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#barLabel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 38.5%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#break {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 38.5%;
}

#showTable {
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.show-table-entry {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.show-table-header {
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AntonPaar User Application</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>Please select a file:</h3>

    <label for="fileList" >File: </label>
    <select id="fileList" onchange="readLines()"></select>

    <br>
    <label for="progress-bar" id="barLabel">Progress: </label>
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    <button id="break" onclick="abortProgress()">Abort</button>
    <br><br>

    <table id="showTable"></table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree with the answers below that Flexbox is the simplest solution. However, I’m sure your curious why the code your wrote isn’t working. Did you try inspecting the page to see what may be causing your expectations to be different from the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple setup would be to use a Flexbox parent element which would vertically and horizontally align the inner elements (Progress, Input, Abort):

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex; /* Create a Flexbox parent container */
  justify-content: center; /* Align Flex items horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* Align Flex items vertically */
  gap: 1rem; /* Give a gap 1rem between the 3 Flex items */
}

#progress-bar{

    border:1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <label id="barLabel">Progress: </label>
  <div id="progress-bar"></div>
  <button id="break">Abort</button>
</div>
```

Remember: the `<div>` elements cannot be [associated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) with `<label>` elements. So, having he label `for` attribute associated with a div (via the for/id 'progress-bar') won't have any effect.

> "Elements that can be associated with a `<label>` element include `<button>`, `<input>` (except for type="hidden"), `<meter>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`."

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply wrap all three in a `div` tag and use `flex`.
Also, you need to change the `margin-left` and `margin-right` for your `barLabel` and 'break'. Here is the code with the changes:

```css
#progress-bar{

    border:1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

#loading-bar{

    background: greenyellow;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;

}

#barLabel{

    float: left;
    /* margin-left: 38.5%; */
    vertical-align: middle;

}

#break{

    float: right;
    /* margin-right: 38.5%; */

}

#showTable{

    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.show-table-entry{

    border-bottom:1px solid black;

}

.show-table-header{

    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    width: 15%;

}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AntonPaar User Application</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h3>Please select a file:</h3>

<label for="fileList" >File: </label>
<select id="fileList" onchange="readLines()"></select>

<br>
  <div class='container'>    
     <label for="progress-bar" id="barLabel">Progress:      </label>
     <div id="progress-bar"></div>
     <button id="break"  onclick="abortProgress()">Abort</button>
    <br><br>
  </div>

<table id="showTable">
</table>

</body>
</html>
```